# How to schedule a TaskCompletionSource.Task with a TaskScheduler?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

```
    public Task<bool> Submit(TaskScheduler ts, Func<bool> work, object state, TaskContinuationOptions taskContinuationOptions)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(state, TaskCreationOptions.None);

        Task t1 = new TaskFactory(_cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskContinuationOptions, ts).StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                tcs.SetResult(work());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }               
        });

        Task<bool> t2 = tcs.Task;
        t2.ContinueWith(OnTaskSignaled);
        return t2;
    }

    public void OnTaskSignaled(Task<bool> signaledTask) 
    {            
        BusinessItem item = (BusinessItem)signaledTask.AsyncState;
        if (signaledTask.IsCanceled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} cancelled: Invalid State", item.Id);
        }
        else if (signaledTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} threw: {1}", item.Id, signaledTask.Exception);
        }
        else if (signaledTask.Result == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Succeeded", item.Id);
            // continue to submit
        }
        else if (signaledTask.Result == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Incomplete, retry", item.Id);
            Submit(_ts2, item.Work, item);
        }
    }
```

In the above example, does the taskContinuationOptions option propagate to TaskCompletionSource.Task?  In debug mode, I can see that t1 and t2 are two different objects.  In fact, if state is passed to StartNew(...), it is only available to t1, but not t2.

TaskFactory in this case is used only to submit work to a specific TaskScheduler, ts.  The fact that it also creates another task makes the code confusing.  Is there a less confusing way to do this?  I don't understand why TaskCompletionSource being a Task producer is not as configurable as TaskFactory.

Comment: Where did you get this code?  If you're creating a Task<T> object, you don't need a TaskCompletionSource object--TCS is generally used for asynchronous actions that aren't implemented with Task<T> (like APM, EAP.  You're effectively creating two tasks using TCS.

Comment: How do I expose the caught exception through Task?  I got the code from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.100).aspx.  I added OnTaskSignaled to the code sample.

Comment: Ok, I see that Task expose the same API.  I was confused by the example on msdn.  thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same thing with `Task<T>`.  you can get at the exception with a try/catch around Result, or peek at the Exception property.  Likely they will be a `AggregateException` and you'll have to look at `InnerExceptions` of the `Flattened` to get the real exception `AggregateExcpetion` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx  I'd recommend using async/await for better exception handling, if you can. (VS2012)

Comment: `"I don't understand why TaskCompletionSource being a Task producer is not as configurable as TaskFactory."`.  `TaskCompletionSource` is *way more configurable* than `TaskFactory`.  You can do *anything* with a TCS, you aren't limited to just a small set of options provided in the constructor the way you are with TaskFactory.  You can do whatever you want to determine what actually does the "work" for a task, it is 100% up to you.  That's the *point* of `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for you to use `TaskCompletionSource`. If you return the value from the lambda, the `Task` returned from `StartNew()` will contain exactly what you want: the result on success and the exception on failure.

Also, I think the `TaskContinuationOptions` in `TaskFactory` work only for continuations that are started directly through the factory (e.g. using [`ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall.aspx)). Because of that, I think you don't need the `TaskFactory` at all, but you should specify the options to each task (the original and the continuation) separately. Though I think it's weird that someone outside of the current method should set how the internal continuation should execute.

And to answer your question: it doesn't make sense to schedule `TaskCompletionSource` with some `TaskFactory`, because `TaskCompletionSource` doesn't actually execute.

With these changes, your code will look like this:

```
public Task<bool> Submit(
    TaskScheduler ts, Func<bool> work, object state,
    TaskContinuationOptions taskContinuationOptions)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => work(), state, _cts.Token);

    task.ContinueWith(OnTaskSignaled, _cts.Token, taskContinuationOptions,
                      TaskScheduler.Default);

    return task;
}
```

Comment: i found this useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx